# Index mongodb data in solr via haystack

Tags: django, mongodb, solr, django-haystack, django-mongodb-engine

Recently, I changed some of my DB data from postgres to mongo in order to get better performance and because of the flexibility of mongodb (my DB is already big, and now I have to support 5 more languages over the same models)

I am using solr with django-haystack to index, but I haven't been able to index straight mongodb models to Solr with haystack.

The mongo backend that I am using is Django MongoDB Engine.

I haven't been able to find much information about it. Maybe it's because doesn't make much sense what I am actually doing.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

What error are you getting, it should be fairly straight forward. You should check if haystack is catching the mongodb engine's post save signal.

HAYSTACK_SIGNAL_PROCESSOR = 'haystack.signals.RealtimeSignalProcessor'

Comment: The problem I am getting, is that haystack is not getting the mongodb app models when indexing. I will have a look into the haystack signal processor and keep you posted. Thanks